# How can I list what driver is used by an interface

Tags: debian, drivers

How can I list what driver is used by an interface (specifically `wlan0`) on a Debian Jessie system?

I tried `sudo lshw -c Network` which works, but shows `driver=brcmfmac`

`/lib/firmware/brcm/` contains 12 brcmfmac drivers. I am interested in which is used.

Comment: `/lib/firmware` doesn't contain any drivers. It contains firmware blobs. `/lib/modules` contains drivers. Finding out what firmware is loaded may not be easy. If you're lucky, there will be something in the kernel log (`/var/log/kern.log`) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `lsmod |grep brc` (in my machine also `grep wifi` worked). 
Then you can get info about module using `modinfo <module>`.
This will inform you about driver and firmware.

Example from my pc:

```
root@debian: lsmod |grep wifi
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl8192se,rtl_pci
mac80211              671744  3 rtl8192se,rtl_pci,rtlwifi
cfg80211              589824  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

root@debian: modinfo rtl8192se
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192S/8191S 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008174sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008173sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008172sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008171sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008192sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
```

Comment: Thanks. This still didn't answer the question (how to go from `wlan0` to details), but is the most useful response, and enabled me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the interface name is `interfaceName`. Then simply run 
`ethtool -i interfaceName` and look in the first line of the result.